# How to deploy a windows developped application using XAMPP on amazon aws free tier using a free windows stack?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xampp, bitnami

I have developped a web application on windows using Xampp and now I would like to deploy it on the cloud. Because my app engine uses a windows specific software I need windows installed on the web server not Linux. I have a free tier bitnami account and a free tier aws  account. none of them seem to give me steps on creating a windows based server and how to deploy an XAMPP based app. This is my first cloud app so I need you to give a tutorial like answer please. Also if you think I can have a work around on Linux I am open to it but bare in mind that I have to install a windows only software on the server to power my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here.

If you want to move your application to the cloud, you can launch a Windows server in AWS and install XAMPP (for development) or the [Bitnami WAMP stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp) (production) to deploy your application in the cloud.

Comment: Thanks I found the steps on aws to do it! However they warn me against using windows (server 2016) to deploy a production app; why is it so? have any idea?